# Bash for all elements in massive exec shut down

Tags: mysql, bash

i have to do shut down of my vm's, smth like garbage collector, my script find name of vm's in database which are empty and ready for off. I have got trouble when i path to massive names of vm the output if echo is trully, but when i try to do turn off it takes only one elenent in mass and didn't path to variable.

How can i do shut down for all elements in massive? and path the names of vm's to property?

```
arr1=($(/usr/bin/mysql --skip-column-names -u $DB_USER  -p$DB_PASS $DB -e "SELECT VM_NAME FROM VM_LIST Where     BUSY="0" AND POOL='LINUX';"))
echo ${#arr1[@]} 

if arr1 -gt 0

then 

for availiable_node in "${arr1[@]}"
do
shutdown $availiable_node
echo $availiable_node
```

Comment: Do you have any hypervisor command to shutdown the VMs? e.g. `xe vm-shutdown`

Answer (score 0):

Though I couldn't understand everything, still if someone wants to do such activity, 
It should be like:

```
#!/bin/bash
vmNode=(db query )

for node in ${vmNode[*]}
do 

echo $node
ssh user@${node} "sudo shutdown -h now" #user should be same on all nodes.
                                        # sudo use is subject to requirement

done
```

Requirements for this to work:

1) `ssh` should be passwordless

2) `sudo` should be passwordless and should not need `tty`

solution will still work if `sudo or ssh` are not password less but you shall have to enter password 2 times for eveynode, once for `ssh` and then for `sudo`

3) The node you are firing this script from, should be last or should not be there in `vmNode` array.

4) If query is fetching node host name then they should be configured in the `/etc/hosts` and `~/.ssh/known_hosts`

**This will work for OS shutdown(*nix) only.**